# javascript jsonp url request

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I have a url which only accepts jsonp request. I have to make an url request and the server would respond with this as output:

```
[{"id":213877,"pic":"https://graph.facebook.com/ariel.barack/picture?type=square","url":"https://angel.co/ariel-barack","name":"Ariel Barack","type":"User"},{"id":109396,"pic":"https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/users/109396-medium_jpg?1405528556","url":"https://angel.co/mattbarackman","name":"Matt Barackman","type":"User"}]
```

I need to output the concatenation of name attributes from the output i.e Ariel Barack+Matt Barackman.

I am currently using this code to do it. Any suggestions on what to do next?

```
function getJSONP(url, success) {

var ud = '_' + +new Date,
    script = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
           || document.documentElement;

window[ud] = function(data) {
    head.removeChild(script);
    success && success(data);
};

script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
head.appendChild(script);

}

getJSONP('https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User', function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: sounds like you just need to loop over the array found in `data`, have you tried using one?

Comment: Ye, but i am not sure whether any data is being read from the url. When i write document.write(data) instead of console.log(data), nothing is being displayed on the browser

Comment: The output that you quote is JSON, not JSONP

Comment: could you please elaborate? I couldnot understand

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
```

It replaces the callback placeholder in the URL with a unique callback name.

Now look at your URL:

```
'https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User'
```

You didn't put a callback placeholder in it.

The replacement replaces nothing, and the service responds with JSON instead of JSONP. That is why it doesn't work.

You need to include `callback=?` in your query string.

Comment: I donot think so, that I need a callback in query string

Comment: @user3371307 — You do need it. It's a fundamental part of how JSONP works.

Comment: I am not very sure whether i really understand this. The documentation for this API says "All responses are of type application/json. JSONP is supported—just pass a callback in the query string. The response will be of type text/javascript". So could you insist me on any modifications?

Comment: @user3371307 — That says if you don't put a callback in the query string, you get JSON and if you do then you get JSONP. You want JSONP so put a callback in the query string. The last line of the answer tells you how.

Comment: suppose i want to use jsonp, the code that i posted in the question should work fine right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because you don't have a callback in the URL.

Comment: I am sorry. The url that I use cannot have a callback placeholder. So that means I have to use json request url for this right?

Comment: So the code that I posted wudnot be working. So any help with json url request?

Comment: No. You are using a JSON URL. That is the problem. Your code needs the response to be JSONP. Put a callback argument into the URL. Then you will get a JSONP response. Then it will work.

Comment: The url which returns me the required output is only this: https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User and i am not allowed any other variations with this

Comment: If you are not allowed to use the service as it is designed to be used then you are screwed. Go and demand that whomever is setting that requirement change it so you are allowed to put a callback argument in the URL as the service expects you to.

Comment: https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User&callback=parse Is this url fine for the code?

Comment: Yes. Expect that `parse` should be `?` when you write your URL because your code is designed to use that to generate a unique URL each time it runs (and depends on the generated callback name to create the callback function)

Comment: So if the url is : https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User&callback=? , it has to work perfectly fine right?

Comment: var names = "";
getJSONP('https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User&callback=?', function(data){
    
for (var ii = 0; ii < data.length; ii++) {
  names += data[ii].name;document.write('append');
}
   document.write(names); 
});

Comment: This is the exact snippet that I am using for concatenation, but not getting the output as desired

Comment: Read your JavaScript error console. *Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.*. Put `document.open()` in there or use DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsonp call is wrong. There are to many ways to do a jsonp call, try with this

```
<script>
    function JSONPHandler(data) {
        var names = "";
        for (var ii = 0; ii < data.length; ii++) {
            names += data[ii].name;
        }
        alert(names);

    };
</script>
<script src="https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User&callback=JSONPHandler">
```

Comment: but when i try document.write(data), i dont see the data that is being read from the url

Comment: Why document.write? use console.log()

Comment: getJSONP('https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User', function(data){
    var names = "";
for (var ii = 0; ii < data.length; ii++) {
  names += data[ii].name;
}
   document.write(names); 
});

Comment: This is the exact snippet that I am using

Comment: So i use this inplace of the whole url request code ?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over data and concatenate the name attribute.

```
var result = "";    
for(var i in data){
   result +=data[i].name;
}
```

Comment: Ye, but i am not sure whether any data is being read from the url. When i write document.write(data) instead of console.log(data), nothing is being displayed on the browser

Comment: Document.write accepts one String's parameter. Data is an array.

Comment: document.write(data.toString()) was what i tried to be very specific

Comment: and even now, if i try document.write(result), i donot see any output. Any help?

Comment: getJSONP('https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User', function(data){
    var names = "";
for (var ii = 0; ii < data.length; ii++) {
  names += data[ii].name;
}
   document.write(names); 
});

Comment: This is the exact snippet that I am using to print the concatenated string